# How to open project as a web application on "Visual studio For Mac Community"

Tags: visual-studio-community

Since I am new to ASP.net and trying to open a web application. but as I could see in Windows we get option as open as web application, In Mac I could not find it.

Please assist if anyone has faced same problem earlier

Answer (score 0):

There is a link that explains asp.net project creation. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app-mac/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-2.0)

Comment: I went through this link already. But this link suggest how to create a project. I want to open existing project